# Common Clickable Header for All Activities in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an application with a common Header in all layouts. I want that whenever the user clicks at the the ImageView with id `btn_home`, the app will go back to a specific activity, my "Main" for instance.

What is the best way to do that?

I know that I can define the `onClick(View v)` for every activity, but maybe there is a better way to do that. Even making every activity be some (via heritage) other that has the `onClick(View v)` defined sounds bad.

header.xml

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1" ...>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/logo_cats"></ImageView>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/btn_home" ...></ImageView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

every layout

```
...
<include layout="@layout/header" android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
...
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can make a custom component out of your header and define 'onClick()' in it. For example, make a new class `Header` that would extend a RelativeLayout and inflate your header.xml there. Then, instead of `<include>` tag you would use `<com.example.app.Header android:id="@+id/header" ...`. No code duplication and the header becomes totally reusable.

UPD: Here's some code examples

header.xml:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/logo" .../>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/label" .../>
    <Button android:id="@+id/login" .../>
</merge>
```

activity_with_header.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" ...>
    <com.example.app.Header android:id="@+id/header" .../>
    <!-- Other views -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Header.java:

```
public class Header extends RelativeLayout {
public static final String TAG = Header.class.getSimpleName();

protected ImageView logo;
private TextView label;
private Button loginButton;

public Header(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public Header(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public Header(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public void initHeader() {
        inflateHeader();
}

private void inflateHeader() {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, this);
    logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.logo);
    label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.label);
    loginButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
}
```

ActivityWithHeader.java:

```
public class ActivityWithHeader extends Activity {
private View mCreate;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_with_header);

    Header header = (Header) findViewById(R.id.header);
    header.initHeader();
    // and so on
}
}
```

In this example, Header.initHeader() can be moved inside Header's constructor, but generally this method provides a nice way to pass on some useful listeners. Hope this will help.

Comment: i can't see the footer at all. can we call 'getSystemService()' method of an activity in non-activity class?. i tried with 'getContext()' but it doesn't display anything.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you without looking at your code. And yes, you can call `getContext()` from the descendants of [View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getContext()).

Comment: What should i do if i want drawer layout?

Comment: I tried this code. But Header is not visible when i try R.id.header. If i try R.layout.header, it throws null pointer exception. ... Can you help me understand what i am missing?

Answer (score 3):

Extend the Activity class and build a MyActivity class for example. In this MyActivity class you could include the code for the onClick.

Now create a layout that just holds your header. Include that layout in your activity layouts.

Extend all your activities from MyActivity - that's it.

If you need the same behaviour in ListActivities create a MyListActivity as well.

Comment: I don't think this is the best way to do that. So much code repetition.

Comment: Code repetition? Where? You extend Activity once, define onClick in there once and use it automatically in all Activities that extend your MyActivity class. Everything is written once, just once. This is the Java way and for your requirement it fits perfect.

Comment: Oh my god, so much code ;-)  Put the onClick code in a seperate class and call it from within these four common Activities. Makes 12 additional lines of code for your whole app.  And it stays at 12 even if you need 100 activities with thousands of lines of code.  If this is way to much for you - what are you thinking about?