# using common Layout and its event in all activities

Tags: android

I have one common layout that has four button at top bar and i am using this layout in all activities by including that common layout in all activities layout 
by

`<include ... >`

But i have to use that 4 buttons click event in all activities 
is there any comman way to create custom actvity that is used in all activites , i have created on activity and implement that 4 button click event in that activity and extends that activity in all actvity but it is not working  for me.
please give me some idea for that.
Thanks

Comment: Hello are you using Tab Activity in your application?

Comment: are u mansi vora and i am not using tab Actvity

Comment: It should work. can you post your code

Comment: Yes I am. Please check answer. I have posted syntax. I hope it helps you.

Comment: I got my solution from here                                 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419715/common-clickable-header-for-all-activities-in-android ,Thanks all for Ur response

Comment: Hello bindalbhai.. Can u tell me the answer of my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698889/how-to-measure-height-width-and-distance-of-object-using-camera

Comment: Hello bindalbhai.. How r u? R u der?

Answer (score 2):

yes,You can make one activity say **HeaderActivity**

in that `onCreate setContentView(R.layout.header);` set **header.xml**

and write your all Button Click events in this class once and

and now in other Activities extend HeaderActivity.
like,

```
public class SecondActivity extends HeaderActivity
{
}
```

To show different layouts ..

put a LinearLayout in header.xml below that buttons and in each other activities use

```
ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.lldata);
ViewGroup.inflate(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listwitter, vg);
```

Here *lldata is LinearLayout in header.xml*

to show different layout in diff activity.

Comment: Thanks, I used similar implementation for my project but I have [this issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11522798/840669). Please answer if you can figure out what is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use basic OOP strategies like you said. Create a parent activity that handles the onClick events. Then all your activities should extend that parent. They will automatically have access to the onClick events as long as the methods are not private.

If you need to do different things onClicks in each activity, it might be worth approaching this differently, and or using a call back style. Example of the basic structure:

```
public class ParentActivity extends Activity {
    public void onMyButtonClick(View v) {
        // do your thing
    }
}

public class ChildActivity extends ParentActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // your activity
    }
}
```

Comment: i have done that but click event of Parentactivity is not Working ChildActivity

Answer (score 1):

1. Define a header layout with 4 buttons and define android:onClick attributes inside xml layout for e.g. `android:onClick="btnHomeClick"`, `android:onClick="btnSearchClick"`....etc.
2. Define an Abstract class by extending Activity and implement all these click method:

   ```
   public void btnHomeClick(View v) {
   }

   public void btnSearchClick(View v)
   {
   }
   ```
3. include that header layout by  tag in your xml layout files.
   Now extends the above activity class in your every activity class.
4. this way you just has to define a click event for once.

Comment: Thanks a Lot sir!!
@Paresh Mayani :)

Comment: @VishalPatoliyaツ Glad that it has helped you!

Answer (score 0):

Hello Bindalbhai..

```
MainActivity myAct = (MainActivity) this.getParent();

TextView myTitleText = (TextView)myAct.findViewById(R.id.txtTitle);
```

It may be helps you. Or you can use **ViewGroup** for this.

Thanks.

Comment: yes But it also requires click event to be declared in all activities  please add your self in this room  http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5764/androiddevlopers

Answer (score 0):

Create a static object in order to listen to the button clicks.Based on this object handle events in all activities.

For example say Constants.class:

```
public class Constants {
    private static int buttonState1;
        public static int getButtonState(){
        return buttonState1;
    }
    public static int  setButtonState(int x){
        buttonState1=x;
    }


}
```

And in your activity:

```
Button bt1=(Button)  findViewById(R.id.bt1);

bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                                   Constants.setButtonState(1);
                         }
            });
```

And  in other activities

```
if(Constants.getButtonState()==1)
                //do something
```