# Navigation between different layouts of my application

Tags: java, android

My app has 4 different screens and I am trying to set up a tab-like structure, only using buttons.
For simplicity I'll just call them A,B,C,D.

Right now in the onCreate method of each Activity, I have 3 button Button listeners (in Activity A, I have listeners for Button B, C, D) that trigger a startActivity when the respective button is pressed.

The problem occurs when I navigate from say A->B and then try to go back B->A using the buttons, my application crashes. I believe this is because A is paused in the background, and trying to start a new instance of it makes the program crash.

So I was wondering if there is a way to resume Activity A without creating a new instance of it?
I was expecting there to be some sort of resumeActivity() Method, but it doesnt seem to exist.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You can use "ViewFlipper" to flip views on runtime

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    // do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: So when I call startActivity() and the activity has already started, and is paused, it will go to the onResume() instead of onCreate()?

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to do this.

1) Set **[LaunchMode](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html)** of Your Activity A to SingleInstance

2) Dont call Activity A with Intent, Just Finish B, It will Automatically show A.

3) See **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471664/using-common-layout-and-its-event-in-all-activities/8471708#8471708)** and make only one base class and extend it elsewhere in A to D and write all button click in Base Class only.(To Simplify your code)

4) If necessary `Override onResume()` of Activity A.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the [TabHost](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html) if you don't want to make the entire functionality yourself.
Here's a tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html

Answer (score 0):

Use a [TabActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html)
And then if you don't want to use the default implementation of the tabs, then I think you would remove the `<TabWidget>` from the xml and use [TabHost.setCurrentTab](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TabHost.html#setCurrentTab(int)) to change which Activity you are on.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [`Fragments`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) instead. Having A, B, C and D be a `Fragment` each and then have one single `Activity` that only handles the navigation between the `Fragments`.