# Want to add header and footer in each activity

Tags: android, android-layout

Hello everyone I wanna add the header and footer logo of my company profile in each activity it is redirected.. So please help me in designing this...

Comment: which layout you are using? past your code.

Comment: well currently in all activities I have used the listview. But latter it may change...

Comment: Have you seen this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8471664/using-common-layout-and-its-event-in-all-activities/8471708#8471708

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an ImageView for both the header & footer,dont forget to use alignparenttop & alignparentbottom respectively.

Comment: Thank karthik...But in each layout i have to implement this isn't there another way??

Comment: have a image in the top... and have another image is in the bottom

Answer (score 0):

You can use fragments for this purpose, or can search merge/include layout concepts to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

rashmi yo have to create a XML file which contains you header logo and after that you have to include that XML file as header in your other XMLs mention below

```
<include layout="@layout/your XML File">
```

try this i think it might help you

Comment: @Harsh Trivedi if you add the XML file with your answer. then the ratio to accept your answer will increase.