# Inflating custom view causes error

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, layout-inflater

I have created a custom view that includes an ImageButton and a TextView. This is my layout:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

     <ImageButton android:id="@+id/image_button"
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

     <TextView android:id="@+id/text_view"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:clickable="false"
               android:layout_margin="1dp" />    
</merge>
```

I also have a class that inherits from RelativeLayout called CustomImageButton. This is part of it's code:

```
public class CustomImageButton extends RelativeLayout {

    ...

    public CustomImageButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        this.attributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomImageButton);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onFinishInflate() {
        super.onFinishInflate();

        ((Activity)getContext()).getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_image_button, this);
        this.setClickable(false);
        setupViewItems();
    }

    private void setupViewItems() {
          // DO STUFF HERE TO THE IMAGE BUTTON AND TEXT VIEW
          // FROM THE CUSTOM ATTRIBUTES 
    }
}
```

These are the custom attribute given to the Custom image button: (attrs.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="CustomImageButton">
        <attr name="image_src" format="integer" />
        <attr name="text" format="string" />
        <attr name="text_size" format="dimension" />
        <attr name="text_top_padding" format="integer" />
        <attr name="text_alginment">
            <enum name="left" value="1"/>
            <enum name="right" value="2"/>
            <enum name="center" value="3"/>
        </attr>
        <attr name="text_color" format="color"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

and finally this is the main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="3" xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.company.product.sp">

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <View
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="2px"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <com.company.product.ui.views.CustomImageButton
            android:id="@id/main_command"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            app:image_src="@drawable/main_activity"
            app:text="@string/item_title"
            app:text_size="@dimen/main_menu_item_text"
            app:text_top_padding="55"
            app:text_alginment="center"
            app:text_color="@android:color/black" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and now, for the problem. When i run my application on android 4.0.2 and higher everything is ok BUT, when i run my app on android 2.2.1 i get

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class <unknown>
```

according to the stack trace (which is VERY uninformative) the exception is thrown from the `CustomImageButton` class in the `onFinishInflate` method when i call the `inflate` method. Any ideas why and how can i fix this?

Comment: hello refere this answer



  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7419715/common-clickable-header-for-all-activities-in-android

Comment: @bindal - Thank you for your reply. The problem is that the CustomImageButton is not initiated via code but via layout.xml.

Comment: Check your packagename in layout com.company.product.ui.views, is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if any of the other two constructors is called (with one or three arguments) - and then this.attributes doesn't get set. This happened in my case.

```
public SelectorButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    _context = context;
}

public SelectorButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    _context = context;
    init(attrs);
}

public SelectorButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    _context = context;
    init(attrs);
}
```

You can see that I am initializing attributes only in second and third constructor.